# Create a custom setxkbmap option

Tags: linux, keyboard, keyboard-layout

Oddly, this seems like it should be something that's been done before: I want to swap the **numbers** and **symbols** on the <kbd>1</kbd>–<kbd>0</kbd> keys across the top of my keyboard so that:

- When I hit the <kbd>6</kbd> key, an `*` is typed instead of a `6`.
- When I hit <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd> the number `6` will display instead of an `*`.

There were several other modifications that I wanted to make, but quickly found that others had already accomplished these layout modifications before using options for `setxkbmap` (like `caps:swapescape`, for example).

---

**Given the above, this is a 3-part question:**

1. Is there an option for swapping numbers and symbols on the top row of my keyboard?
2. Whether there is or not, is there any way to find out if such a thing exists without having to manually browse the `*.lst` and `*.xml` files in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/`?
3. Finally, if I were to create an option for `setxkbmap`, what would be an ideal approach, and how would I see about contributing my option back to the community?

---

*As for question 3:*

- I have attempted to create the option without success (`setxkbmap` silently fails and I'm not even confident in my approach).
- I can't find where the project is hosted.
- Aside from `man setxkbmap` and various blog posts that touch on the topic, I've been unable to find any documentation on any of this.

Comment: “Oddly, this seems like it should be something that's been done before”: Yes; this is how the standard French layout works. `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/fr` defines the keys in the normal, painstaking way, i.e. it defines the whole numeric row manually.  It would be nice if there was a “swap these two levels” option, but I haven’t heard of it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## Question 2:

For a list of all options available, you can execute `localectl list-x11-keymap-options`.  This seems to only provide you with the options themselves, not the descriptions, so a better approach may be to execute the following on the *XKB* `*.lst` files:

```
for f in /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/*.lst; do sed -ne '/^\! option$/{s///; :a' -e 'n;p;ba' -e '}' $f; done | sort -u
```

*[(sed reference)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/56429/how-to-print-all-lines-after-a-match-up-to-the-end-of-the-file)**

If you're looking for something related to swapping numbers, you can append `| grep -i num`, revealing several options for working with the numpad/keypad.  Unfortunately, I think that all of the layouts have the numbers laid out in the templates related to *alphanumeric* characters, meaning they're built in to the regional layouts themselves (or the variant, in the case of `dvorak`).

## Question 1:

There are three approaches that you can take.

#### Override layouts using `xmodmap`

You can create a somewhat versatile approach by creating an `.Xmodmap` file in your home to override mappings, as described on the Arch Wiki [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/xmodmap).

Here is an example configuration: https://github.com/karma0/layouts/blob/master/home/.Xmodmap

**Steps:**

1. Drop `.Xmodmap` in your home.
2. Add the line `xmodmap $HOME/.Xmodmap` to your `.profile`

---

#### A quick and dirty, but flexible approach:

1. Run `xkbcomp -xkb $DISPLAY xkbmap` to generate a file `xkbmap` with your current configuration in it.
2. Modify it to match the desired configuration.  Here's an example:

> Original:
>
> ```
> key <AE01> {         [               1,          exclam ] };                                                                                                       
> key <AE02> {         [               2,              at ] };                                                                                                       
> key <AE03> {         [               3,      numbersign ] };                                                                                                       
> key <AE04> {         [               4,          dollar ] };                                                                                                       
> key <AE05> {         [               5,         percent ] };                                                                                                       
> key <AE06> {         [               6,     asciicircum ] };                                                                                                       
> key <AE07> {         [               7,       ampersand ] };                                                                                                       
> key <AE08> {         [               8,        asterisk ] };                                                                                                       
> key <AE09> {         [               9,       parenleft ] };                                                                                                       
> key <AE10> {         [               0,      parenright ] };
> ```
>
> Modified:
>
> ```
> key <AE01> {         [               exclam,        1 ] };                                                                                                         
> key <AE02> {         [               at,            2 ] };                                                                                                         
> key <AE03> {         [               numbersign,    3 ] };                                                                                                         
> key <AE04> {         [               dollar,i       4 ] };                                                                                                         
> key <AE05> {         [               percent,       5 ] };                                                                                                         
> key <AE06> {         [               asciicircum,   6 ] };                                                                                                         
> key <AE07> {         [               ampersand,     7 ] };                                                                                                         
> key <AE08> {         [               asterisk,      8 ] };                                                                                                         
> key <AE09> {         [               parenleft,     9 ] };                                                                                                         
> key <AE10> {         [               parenright,    0 ] };
> ```

3. Execute the command `xkbcomp -w 0 xkbmap $DISPLAY` to load the new configuration.
4. Get the command to run at startup using `xinitrc` or similar.

---

#### Modify your layout and add a new variant

1. Open up your favorite layout file (likely under `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols`).  We'll use the `us` file for this example.
2. Find your favorite variant within the file; `workman-intl` if you're like me.
3. Assuming you want to replicate the `workman-intl` layout, you can duplicate that section, and modify it similar to how I did here (note that this is copy/pasted from the `intl` template and the first and second columns are simply swapped):

> ```
>  partial alphanumeric_keys                                                                                      
>  xkb_symbols "workman-programmer" {
>      include "us(workman-intl)"
>      name[Group1]= "English (Workman, intl., with dead keys and num/sym swapped)";
>
>      key <AE01> { [ exclam,         1,    exclamdown, onesuperior ] };
>      key <AE02> { [ at,             2,   twosuperior, dead_doubleacute ] };
>      key <AE03> { [ numbersign,     3, threesuperior, dead_macron ] };
>      key <AE04> { [ dollar,         4,      currency, sterling ] };
>      key <AE05> { [ percent,        5,      EuroSign, dead_cedilla ] };
>      key <AE06> { [ dead_circumflex,6,    onequarter, asciicircum ] };
>      key <AE07> { [ ampersand,      7,       onehalf, dead_horn ] };
>      key <AE08> { [ asterisk,       8, threequarters, dead_ogonek ] };
>      key <AE09> { [ parenleft,      9, leftsinglequotemark, dead_breve ] };
>      key <AE10> { [ parenright,     0, rightsinglequotemark, dead_abovering ] };
> };
> ```
>
> The `xkb_symbols` line defines the name of your *variation*; the `include` line borrows everything you need from the variation of your choice within the file (here, it's the `workman-intl` variation in the `us` layout).  Then, the definitions you want are what follows.
>   4. Add your new definition to `/usr/share/xkb/rules/base.xml` to the end of the `variantList` tag.  Here's the one I used:
>
> ```
>         <variant>                                                                                              
>           <configItem>                                                                                         
>             <name>workman-programmer</name>                                                                    
>             <description>English (Workman, intl., with dead keys and num/sym swapped)</description>                  
>            </configItem>                                                                                       
>          </variant>
> ```

5. Add the new variant and description to the `! variant` section of `/usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/base.lst` as:

> ```
>       workman-programmer    us: English (Workman, intl., with dead keys and num/sys swapped)'
> ```

6. Restart your Xorg server.
7. Setup the `setxkbmap` command to run using the new variant.  Here's the one for this demonstration: `setxkbmap -layout us -variant workman-programmer -option`

## Question 3:

Try as you might, you're not going to find the documentation until you start looking for `xkb` documentation, which is situated within the `xorg` ecosystem.

The best write-up out there is probably this one:

https://www.charvolant.org/doug/xkb/html/index.html

**QUOTE:**

> *Before you read this, please understand that I never wanted to write this document, being grossly under-qualified, but I always wanted to read it, and this was the only way.*

Additionally, here are a list of links as well to get started on learning all of the intricacies of the `xkb` system in `xorg`: https://www.x.org/wiki/XKB/

***Note:*** most of the documentation references relative paths within `xkb` as it is installed on your system.  This is typically under `/usr/share/X11/xkb`

---

If you wish to contribute, this project lives under the `xorg`, which provides developer documentation here: https://www.x.org/wiki/guide/, or better, here: https://www.x.org/wiki/Development/

Comment: Great answer! It's startling how difficult xkb is.
I wonder if it would be possible to package a variant or layout in some kind of file to share or simply keep for myself to use in different Linux installations.